# codeblocks, single project, many executables

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I use [Code::Blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeblocks) and C++ . My project should build multiple executables (set of small tools that use shared libraries).

How to set up CB to generate multiple binaries, each with its own `main()`?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look into [CodeBlock's manuel](http://www.codeblocks.org/docs/main_codeblocks_en.html), specifically chapter 1.8, where it has this workspace example :

> A project A contains fundamental functions which are made available to
>   other projects in the form of a library. Now, if the sources of this
>   project are modified, then the library has to be rebuilt. To maintain
>   consistency between a project B which uses the functions and project A
>   which implements the functions, project B has to depend on project A.
>   The necessary information on the dependencies of projects is stored in
>   the relevant workspace, so that each project can be created
>   separately. The usage of dependencies makes it also possible to
>   control the order in which the projects will be generated. The
>   dependencies for projects can be set via the selecting the menu
>   ’Project’ /’Properties’ and then clicking the ’Project’s dependencies’
>   button.