# How organize opensource C++ project with IDE to share it on github

Tags: c++, git, codeblocks, portability, project-organization

I would like to know (according to [Principle of Least Surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)) how to organize C++ project with tradeoffs, for example, so that it can be easily shared over `git` (e.g. on github), or make it easy for anybody who is interested to import the source files into his environment.

As an example I would refer to `Code::Blocks` since I currently starting to use it, but the question should be more general for any IDE.

---

**How I currently do:**

I have directory structure like this ( dictionaries starts with `/`, comment with `//` ):

```
/.git             // git repo metadata
/common           // source code shared between projects
   /math
   /physics
   /GraphicsUtils
/common_data      // shared data (resources)
/apps             // executable projects ( use cases )
   /SailWar       // game about fighting sail boats
   /AirCraftSimulator
   /SpaceShipSimulator
/libs             // dynamic library projects
   /OrbitalMechanics
```

In each project folder for particular executable program I have this structure:

```
/SailWar
  /bin         // CodeBlocks binary output
  /data        // my datafiles (resources) required for program to run
  /src         // my source code
  /obj         // CodeBlocks compiled objects files
  main.cpp  
  makefile    
  program.x       // binary
  SailWar.cbp     // CodeBlocks project file
  SailWar.depend  // CodeBlocks .depend
  SailWar.layout  // CodeBlocks .layout
  test            // bash script to make clean, make and run the binary
```

In `.git/info/exclude` I have:

`*~  *.pyc  *.o  *.a  *.so  *.x   bin   obj   .depend   .layout`

to make sure that only source files ( not the output and temporary files ) are uploaded to `github`

---

**What I'm not happy with / sure about:**

1. Should I keep ( track ) `.depend   .layout` in git ?
2. Is `CodeBlocks` project `.cbp` protable and genral enought or I have to still keep the `makefile` way of compilation. Best would be if CodeBlocks can use makefile instead of `.cbp`
3. when compiled binary is put to `/bin` it does not have correct path to `/data`
4. I'm not exactly sure how to best connect shared code `/common` and resources `/common_data`. Currently I put `../../common` into compiler search paths ... but I'm not sure if it is the best way.
5. I would probably prefer to make a single project file for everything (all executables, all libraries in one). I think it would make it more clear for any potential user who download it from `github`. But that is probably not possible (?) (I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411905/codeblocks-single-project-many-executables) about that.)

Comment: You might want to take this to http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @AndrewCheong when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat - Got it, thanks. What should the user be recommended to do? Delete this post before posting on the other site? Or wait for migration.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently undertaking a pretty big project with many moving parts, so I had to come up with a good way of organizing all my paths so that there was some kind of order to the madness.

Basically, I have a root directory where all my project subfolders reside, and then each project folder has an include folder, but all projects use the same output folder.  I also use different .workspace files to organize the different projects into groups.  This way I can keep a deterministic folder structure for all my project (all inside the same folder), but still keep them organized.

```
   \root\develop\.workspace
   \root\develop\[project]\.cbp       
   \root\develop\[project]\include
   \root\develop\[project]\obj
   \root\develop\bin
   \root\develop\external\bin
   \root\develop\external\include
```

If you want, you can take a look by checking out the source tree and going through the numerous projects and project options.  THis directory structure supports multiple libraries, executables, and external dependencies.  Its definitely worth a look.
https://github.com/zackeryfix/ngen/tree/master/develop/now

Answer (score -1):

Making your project depend on IDE is bad idea. It is one of the reasons `cmake` was created. As such, I'd recommend you to use CMake as your build system and whatever IDE you like, that supports managing CMake projects.

My personal choice is KDevelop, for instance.

Comment: QtCreator uses cmake aswell

Comment: BTW, CMake can generate projects for several IDE.

Comment: This is a personal opinion,  This has no direction for the OP, and gives little advice on the issue they are experiencing.  -1